# How to create a side panel that can be called from any page with Phonon Framework?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, phonon

I'm using [Phonon](http://phonon.quarkdev.com/) to make a hybrid app. It's my first time using this framework.

I am looking at the documentation for [side panels](http://phonon.quarkdev.com/docs/side-panels) and I see an attribute called `data-page`, which sets what page can call that panel.

If I want a global panel, which can be called from any page, what value do I set on it? I've tried just removing this attribute, but it made the panel to stop working on all pages. Do I need to repeat the same piece of code multiple times? (*really?*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My response is late, but it can help.
The recent versions of Phonon support this feature now.
You can pass multiple pages with the attribute `data-page`.
For example: `data-page="page1, page2"`

[Documentation for side panels](http://phonon.quarkdev.com/docs/side-panels)

Comment: Thank you! At [the project](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ml.jefrey.bitycoon) I was working on at the time of this post I ended up repeating the sidebar panel code, but it's good to know that this feature is now supported for the next projects!